# PCI-E v1 2 and 3 differences in mining?

Tags: hashpower, gpu-mining, mining-setup

Is there any difference in hashrate if I mine from mainboard with pci-e v1 v2 or v3. Also is there difference if I use x1 slot with extension to x16?

Comment: You need to clarify if you're doing Bitcoin with a dedicated ASIC, or (wasting your electricity) with Litecoin

Comment: waste my electricity with litecoin ??? why? I am mining litecoin yes but I dont think its wasting of electricity. Its the same like bitcoin and mb it will be the same fate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it does not matter. Cheap 1x-16x extensions may either burn out or not work properly though, a powered one is essential.